# How to make two processes signalling each others continuously?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I want to simulate a game server that should continuously send and receive signals with its parent. The scenario is as follows:

- Parent sends signal to game.
- Game catches the signal and sends a signal to the parent.
- Parent catches the signal and sends again a signal to game.

and so on...

The problem is that the stops receiving or sending after the first lap:

```
static int game_s;
void game()
{   
    printf("game\n");
    signal(SIGUSR1,game);
    sleep(1);
    kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
    pause();
}
void parent()
{
    printf("parent\n");
    signal(SIGUSR1,parent);
    sleep(1);
    kill(game_s,SIGUSR1);
    pause();
}
void main()
{

    game_s = fork();
    if(game_s>0)
    {       
        signal(SIGUSR1,parent);
        sleep(1);
        kill(game_s,SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }
    else
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1,game);
        pause();
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

```
game
parent
```

Why it stopped here? Shouldn't the game server catch parent's signal and print "game" again...

Comment: Isn't the child is signalling the child and the parent is signalling itself, the parent in your code. In this situation, I usually introduce semaphores and two of the kind. One for the parent to wait and one for the child to wait and 2 while loops

Comment: Signals are mostly a bad choice to implement IPC. There are other ways: SHM, pipes, sockets, MQs

Comment: The child is not signalling itself, it sends SIGUSR1 to game_s which stores the pid of the created child... isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the reception of a specific signal is blocked from the moment a process received this specific signal until the related signal handler had been left.

From `man 3 signal`:

> ```
> void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> When a signal occurs, and func points to a function, it is implementation-defined whether the equivalent of a:
>
> ```
>          signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
> ```
>
> is executed or the implementation prevents some implementation-defined set of signals (at least including sig) from occurring until the current signal handling has completed.

To change this behaviour establish the signal handling via `sigaction()` instead of `signal()` (which one should do any ways for portability reasons).

`sigaction()` takes a `struct sigaction`. The member `sa_flags` of the latter should have `SA_NODEFER` set.

From [Linux' `man 2 sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> **SA_NODEFER**
>
> Do not prevent the signal from being received from within its own signal handler.  This flag is meaningful only when establishing a signal handler.

[POSIX words this differently](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigaction.3p.html):

> **SA_NODEFER**
>
> If set and *sig* is caught, *sig* shall not be added to the
>                        thread's signal mask on entry  to  the  signal  handler
>                        unless it is included in *sa_mask*.  Otherwise, *sig* shall
>                        always be added to the thread's signal mask on entry to
>                        the signal handler.

---

Be aware that each signal handler gets it's own stack allocated each time it gets invoked, so sooner or later this recursive ping-pong ends up in an out-of-memory condition.

Comment: Thank you alk, that solved the problem. I was using sigaction but I used signal() in the example for simlicity, BUT I missed the flag SA_NODEFER. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Use message queues, or shared memory to do this.  As stated above, this will eventually run out of memory and it will crash.